# Get start with RxJs

Tags: rxjs

I recently begin learning RxJs and now I can work with it in Angular 2+ projects. My question is how can I work with RxJs without Angular, React etc.

I just want to have a pure RxJs project. Which 'npm' package needs to be installed?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use it in browser use browserify

1.install rxjs npm package

> npm install rxjs

2. install browserify

> npm install -g browserify

3.work on your project.js that include rxjs module.

4.then use browserify to convert your project.js to use it in html

> $ browserify project.js -o bundle.js

here's good tutorial showing every steps

https://miguelmota.com/blog/getting-started-with-rxjs/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20325087)

Comment: @ALollz thank you for letting me know, i'm still a newb on stackoverflow and didn't know the drill.